# Is it possible to set css attributes top, bottom, left and right with bootstrap 4 classes?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

How do I set top/bottom/left/right values of an object using bootstrap classes, is there a class or method within bootstrap 4?

Not the margins or padding.

I've looked at the bootstrap docs on spacing and position.

Anything like this?

```css
.t-0 // top: 0;
.trbl-0 // top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
```

Am I dreaming?

Comment: do you want to add new class or modify in existing class? suppose if you want to add custom style add it in your `head` tag

Comment: the closest you can have is this : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/position/

Comment: Why would my question get voted down? Thanks for tip too Temani

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, Bootstrap doesn't have anything that does this. You will need to add that manually in your style sheet.

Comment: The position classes from bootstrap are useful, but there was no way to escape specifying top, right, bottom, left manually. Viraj is correct. Thanks!